# Why is "VariableDeclaratorId expected" in declaring methods in an interface?

Tags: java, methods, interface, variable-declaration

when you're creating an interface, why do you have to give the Variable ID's ? You're just making an interface which is essentially a contract.

Why can't my method me like this:

```
method(int);
```

and has to be

```
method(int x);
```

We are not implementing the methods. I don't see the use of the x here.

Comment: Variable declaration should be done as a part of method declaration or implementation if the method is parametarized.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You mean if a method has parameters, the variable should be declared. But why? There is no need for that in an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, there is no need for parameter names in interfaces, but because that is how methods are generally defined, and has become a requirement.

It also makes the code a lot more readable and maintainable. If there were 5 integers in a row, you would implement that class and have no clue what each of them mean. Even a descriptive method name would not be able to clue you in on that.